# How to export windows azure table storage to csv file using c#?

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

I am new using C# and Azure Table Storage. I have already created a code in C# wherein I can create a table everyday. I named the table in this format.

```
projecttable20140310
```

I want to export the table that I have created using C# into CSV. And make it automatically. How can I export windows azure table into CSV file using the c# code? Where do I need to start?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the csvtools.azure nuget package. It should be able to do the job. Here is the author's blog on how to use it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/08/03/converting-between-azure-tables-and-csv.aspx

```
Install-Package csvtools.azure
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and [built a small library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Medienstudio.Azure.Data.Tables.CSV/) built on the new Azure.Data.Tables SDK that does the export with correct CSV headers + types so it can be re-imported properly. It should also be compatible with Azure Storage Explorer / azcopy. With that you can export to CSV file or to Azure BLOB Storage in a few lines of code.

```cs
// Export all rows from the table to a CSV file
using StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText("test.csv");
await _tableClient.ExportCSVAsync(writer);

// Export all rows as CSV to Azure BLob Storage
BlobContainerClient containerClient = new(BlobConnectionString, "testcontainer");
var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("test.csv");
var stream = await blobClient.OpenWriteAsync(true, new BlobOpenWriteOptions() { HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "text/csv" } });
using StreamWriter writer = new(stream);
await _tableClient.ExportCSVAsync(writer);
```